# 6 items in BottomNavigationView Android

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, bottomnavigationview

According to design, BottomNavigationView has 6 items. But when I've finished 6-th screen and tried to connect it I got exception. Now I know that BottomNavigationView can consist of max 5 items.

Maybe somebody know how to solve this problem? Maybe external libraries, custom BottomNavigationView or something else

I tried googling but find only old thread here without solving

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide code so that those trying to help have the necessary information. Be detailed and be sure to search for your answer prior to asking the question again ;). cheers

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.